# MySQL: How can I avoid mysql backlog?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running this query in my slave machine.

**Query:**

`select ID from audit where app='accounts'`

**explain output**

```
    +----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | IAMAccountAudit | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 155658522 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
```

After Execution , my slave machine was running behind the master.

```
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 182.31.251.94
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: bin.001487
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 2967065
               Relay_Log_File: 172-relay-bin.004312
                Relay_Log_Pos: 43303861
        Relay_Master_Log_File: bin.001486
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 43303721
              Relay_Log_Space: 55397036
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 365
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1302078
```

It's keep increasing .

How can I avoid the mysql backlog? .

Answer (score 2):

It would help a bit if I had a table schema to work with. However from what I can see your query is not using a index and sequentially reading through the table from the first record to the last record one by one.

As the query has to examine roughly 155,658,522 or 155 million rows it is going to cause a resource drain on the server. Since the query has no appropriate index on the column you are querying(`key`= `null` in explain output) the rows are getting a read lock issued on them one by one.

While this read is happening it is possible for MySQL to block the replication activity i.e. block updates to the rows being read.MySQL will then queue these updates as they cannot complete. This problem is due to ACID compliancy of the server and not threading etc. Since I dont have table information such as engine this is all a educated guess at best.

Suggestions:

1. Index the app column on the table allowing you to do the select faster. With a index on the app column MySQL will do a b-tree search on the table instead of a sequential search. You query will run faster issuing less locks thus it will be faster and more light weight. The downside is that it will slightly delay updates and inserts on this table as there is an additional index to maintain.
2. Unless you need to the nano-second real time replication leave the system as is. Keep in mind that replication falling behind is not a problem if there is no requirements for real time data. Replication failing is much worse.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: We are using innodb engine.